# Trying to link to the D: drive from the C: drive in HTML

Tags: html

I'm setting up a website that hosts my movies and TV shows and allows me to stream them with a decent UI, now I have this problem where I can't acces a different drive from the one my website is hosted on. Here is my code: `<a class="mbox"  href="E:\Nýjar Myndir\47Ronin\47ronin.avi">The Addams Family</a>` what happens when I try to use this is that the links acts like it's dead and when I manually enter it through the Inspect Element feature in Chrome it says 403: Access Denied. So, what should I do?

Comment: Try webserver (apachi or IIS) , WAMP or XAMPP, don't know what computer you are using.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing your path with `file://`?

Comment: This is a security feature in modern browsers (to prevent hostile web sites from accessing local files) that is extremely difficult, if not impossible, to circumvent.

Comment: I am using Apache to host the server, and I have tried using the file:// prefix, this doesn't wor either but when I force the link to open with Inspect Element the file downloads instead of streaming